# Increment Progress Bar Based off ListBox Selection

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have a progress bar which I increment after each process completes.  I have a list box with 10 possible selections.  If for example, only 2 items are selected how could I code to make sure that the progressbar will still hit 100%?  This is how I have been doing it, but this only works if all 10 items are selected..

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains("1"))
{
  backgroundworker.ReportProgress(5);
  //Do This
  backgroundworker.ReportProgress(10);
}
if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains("2"))
{
  backgroundworker.ReportProgress(15);
  //Do This
  backgroundworker.ReportProgress(20);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Untested)

Well after sleeping on it and drinking lots of coffee I think I have found a viable solution to my issue.  The total proress that the progressbar should show would be 100.  If their are 10 possible items and all 10 are selected each item should show 10.  However, I am needing to account for not all items being selected so I need to capture the number of items selected.  Using Linq

```
var count = (frim item in listbox1.Items where item.Selected select item).Count();
```

Should return the number of items selected then I would divide that by 100 to get the count of how much each item should incrememnt

```
var incrementamount = count/100;
```

And viola that is the amount that each item should increment

```
if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains("1"))
{
  //Do This
  backgroundworker.ReportProgress(incrementamount);
}
if (ListBox1.SelectedItems.Contains("2"))
{
  //Do This
  backgroundworker.ReportProgress(incrementamount);
}
```